# How to remove the noise in the given image so that the ocr output be perfect?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

[image]

I have done otsu thresholding on this bengali text image and use tesseract to OCR but the output is very bad. What preprocessing should I apply to remove the noise? I want to deskew the image as well, as it has slight skewed.
My code is given below

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import codecs
image = cv2.imread("crop2.bmp", 0)
(thresh, bw_img) = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

img = Image.fromarray(bw_img)
text = tesserocr.image_to_text(img, lang='ben')
file = codecs.open("output_text", "w", "utf-8")
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

Comment: provide your input image... maybe Otsu is not a good choice.

Comment: I have added input image in the top of the question

Comment: Is that really the original image? It looks like it has gone through a fax machine! This is a problem much more difficult than what can be answered here, I think.

Comment: Hi @dojo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the noises by removing small connected components that might improve the accuracy. You would also need to get optimum value for noisy components threshold value.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'D:\Image\st5.png',0)
ret, bw = cv2.threshold(img, 128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

connectivity = 4
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(bw, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1]; nb_components = nb_components - 1
min_size = 50 #threshhold value for small noisy components
img2 = np.zeros((output.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nb_components):
    if sizes[i] >= min_size:
        img2[output == i + 1] = 255

res = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)
```

Denoised image:

[image]